# compiling in linux using g++

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I have following code which is simply tokenizing an array and then deviding on the basis of '<' and '>' characters. It is running fine in VS community 2019 but when I run it in Linux using g++ command it gives
Free(): invalid pointer
and
Aborted (core dumped)
errors. What am I doing wrong.
PS: error seems to be in the instructions where I am deallocating b in rangbrk and langbrk because when I put it  in comments it runs fine in Linux too. But it runs fine in VS 2019 anyways.

```
//#include <sys/types.h>
//#include <sys/wait.h>
//#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
//#include <unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
//_________________________________________________________
int reads(char str[])
{//a simple function to get input
    int s = 1;
    char  buffer[100];
    cout << "enter command" << endl;
    cin.getline(buffer, 100);
    if (strlen(buffer) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Couldnt get input\n";
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(buffer); i++)
    {
        str[i] = buffer[i];
        if (buffer[i] == 32)
            s++;
    }
    return s;
}
//____________________________________________________________
int tokenizing(char** a, char str[], char buff[50], int x)
{//a function to devide a complete string into smaller parts
 //also stores '/bin/command' into buff to pass as first parameter of execvp
    int k = 0, m = 0;
    bool check = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        a[i] = new char[50];
        for (int j = 0; str[k] != 32; j++)
        {
            if (str[k] == 0)
            {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
            a[i][j] = str[k];
            if (i == 0)
                buff[j + 5] = str[k];
            k++;
            a[i][j + 1] = 0;
            if (i == 0)
                buff[j + 6] = 0;
        }
        m++;
        k++;
        if (check)
            break;
    }
    return m;
}
//__________________________________________________________
void rangbrk(char**& a, char**& b, int& x, char  filename[])
{//saperates the array before and after '>'
    for (int i = 0; i < (x - 2); i++)
    {
        b[i] = new char[50];
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    b[x - 2] = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        filename[i] = a[x - 1][i];
    }
    char** c;//temprory pointer to swap a and b
    c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
    x = x - 2;
    for(int i=0;i<x-1;i++)
    {
    delete [] b[i];
    }
     b=NULL;
}
//__________________________________________________________
void langbrk(char** &a, char** &b, int& x, int index, char  filename[])
{//saperates the array before and after '<'
    int  k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        if ((i != index) && (i != index - 1))
        {
            b[k] = new char[50];
            for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            {
                b[k][j] = a[i][j];
                
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
    b[x - 2] = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        filename[i] = a[index - 1][i];
    }
    char** c;//temprory pointer to swap a and b
    c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
    x = x - 2;
    for(int i=0;i<x-1;i++)
    {
    if(b[i]!=NULL)
    delete [] b[i];
    }
    b=NULL;
}
//__________________________________________________________
int main()
{
    char buff[50] = { "/bin/" };
    char str[100];
    char exit[5] = { 'e','x','i','t',0 };
    char outfile[50];
    char infile[50];
    int x = reads(str);
    char** a;
    a = new char* [x];
    int s = tokenizing(a, str, buff, x);
    a[s] = NULL;
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != NULL; i++)
        cout << a[i] << endl;

    cout << s << endl;;
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        if (a[i][0] == '>')//checks if it need to print in a file
        {
            cout << i;
            char** b;
            b = new char* [s - 2];
            rangbrk(a, b, s, outfile);
            flag = true;
            cout << "New" << endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
                cout << a[j] << endl;
            i = 0;
        }
        else if (a[i][0] == '<')
        {
            cout << i;
            char** c;
            c = new char * [s - 2];
            langbrk(a, c, s, i, infile);
            cout << "New" << endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
                cout << a[j] << endl;
            i = 0;
        }
    }

   
}
```

The reads function gets input, tokenizing tokenized the string in form of words. langbrk copies the string having index 1 less than index of '<' in infile and removes them both from main char** a. rangbrk removes '>' and string succeeding it from a and stores it in outfile

Comment: Somewhere in the above you will have Undefined Behaviour.  You can remove all the pointers by using `std::vector` and `std::string`.  This will make analysis easier.  Failing this compile for and use Address Sanitizer or some other tool for detecting out of bounds access.

Comment: You can use GDB to debug core dumped errors. Since C++ does not have good segmentation errors, this is probably your best choice

Comment: One obvious thing: You send `str` in to `tokenizing` uninitialized and then read values from it (`str[k] != 32`). You've got UB right there.

Comment: note that "runs fine" is not the same as "is correct".

Comment: This is mix of C and C++ style: bad idea. If you want to get into C++, use standard library headers (`<iostream>` instead of `<stdio.h>`) and use the available containers, instead of raw arrays.